# regexp_extract in scala data frame is giving the error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert the below Hive SQL statement into Spark dataframe and getting the error.

```
trim(regexp_extract(message_comment_txt, '(^.*paid\\s?\\$?)(.*?)(\\s?toward.*)', 2))
```

Sample data: `message_comment_txt = "DAY READER, paid 12.76 toward the cost"`

I need to get the output as `12.76`

Please help me to provide equivalent spark dataframe statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try with **`paid\\s+(.*?)\\s+toward`** regex.

```
df.withColumn("extract",regexp_extract(col("message_comment_txt"),"paid\\s+(.*?)\\s+toward",1)).show(false)
//for case insensitive
df.withColumn("extract",regexp_extract(col("message_comment_txt"),"(?i)paid\\s+(.*?)\\s+(?i)toward",1)).show(false)
//+--------------------------------------+-------+
//|message_comment_txt                   |extract|
//+--------------------------------------+-------+
//|DAY READER, paid 12.76 toward the cost|12.76  |
//+--------------------------------------+-------+
```